# Why does Vision gives me this text relevance on the picture?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

This is the image that I'm scanning

[image]

So the first result is **Heb**, why it isn't **1350**? which is in second place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ordering is based on the position in the image, not size or score, since there is no 'Score' response for text. Presumably the response is sorted by the vertices of the bounding polygon of the text.